# How to research pay rates per document?

Tags: job-search, salary, job-description

Today I found a job posting for an RFP writer which asks us for our payment/compensation expectations. They pay per Proposal completed.

I'm not familiar enough with the job to know how many hours are involved in writing one, so I tried looking at sources such as Salary.com. Not surprisingly, they only list salaries, not pay-per-item.

Where can I research typical pay rates for this type of documentation?

Comment: RFPs vary so wildly in how many hours of work they could take to complete, requesting a flat RFP price is something that would only make sense if the type of work were very routine. It seems to me that either the company doesn't know what they are asking for, they do and they are predatory (fishing to underpay), or they are only interested in someone with enough experience in their area that they already have a great idea of how long it should take and what it should cost. None of these are very good meta-signals for you. Beware the risk of such uncertainty, at least.

Answer (score 5):

> Where can I research typical pay rates for this type of documentation?

Search for companies that provide RFP-writing services. For example: https://www.thewritersforhire.com/pricing/

This gives you a feel for what a company would pay a company to write RFPs. Since you are not a company, you would likely demand less.

You could also look at the "gig" sites to see what other individuals would charge:
https://www.fiverr.com/search_results/gigs?query=rfp+writing

Answer (score 1):

RFP writing is long and daunting process.
I was involved in several RFP proposals write-ups and they a widely different even in the same industry.

Usually, when company looking for outside writer, meaning state of things is NOT the best and you will have to hunt the stakeholders for sections fill-up.

Prior to issuing number, ask when is the deadline as you may need at least 2 months IMHO

Comment: I don't think I can do that - they want the number in my cover letter at the same time as the resume.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson If its direct hire, you can reply to the ad with questions

Answer (score 1):

They are looking for a company or freelancer to write their RFPs. If you have never done that you don't have any idea how to formulate your proposal for the job.

An RFP is a request for proposal, in which one organization is asking others to submit bids for a project or a contract. For example a government agency writes an RFP to have technology companies design, build, and administer a cloud based system to allow in-field technicians to report their data and produce reports. AN RFP can be for as $10K project, or as large as multi-billion dollar project.

There is no way to say I will produce an RFP for $x without knowing many more details. This job advertisement is a RFP, and they are asking you the potential RFP writer to respond to that RFP with details on how you will do the job and what the costs will be.

Answer (score -2):

They are asking too much and don't know the process. I would avoid that place like the plague. I've been doing this for 15 years and I'd never make an estimate sight unseen.